# ODE output variation in $\frac{dy}{dx}=y^x$ solution

Tags: differential-equations

[Output differences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3748351/is-it-possible-to-solve-fracdydx-yx/3748413#3748413)  were noted in my answer (Math SE) that slightly varied from time to time. So far unable to find the source of my error. The program is given in the link.

Also I modified `Mathematica` first order code given by Ruslan to second order, but noted no change in output.

```
    ns = {5, 9, 18, 25};
Table[sol[n][x_] = 
   NDSolveValue[{y''[x] == y'[x] (Log[y[x]] + x y'[x]/y[x]), 
     y'[0] == 1, y[0] == n}, y[x], {x, -2, 2}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 30], {n, ns}];
Plot[Table[If[# > 0, #, Indeterminate] &@sol[n][x], {n, ns}], {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 200}, PlotPoints -> 30, GridLines -> Automatic,
  ImageSize -> 600, AspectRatio -> 0.4, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, 
 AxesLabel -> {X, Y}]
```

Request your help to find cause of output variabilities in my code and why it is in variance with Rulan's first/second order codes.

I expected higher accuracy in the choice of second order.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to avoid stiffness messages completely. In the documentation Wolfram Inc. states, this message corresponds to the fail of the solutions finding process.

It seems that the solution has more than one branch for negative values. So I selected the lower sense-making value for the lower bound of the integration interval for `NDSolve`.

I evaluated a problematic value at `x= 1.5875538677415637`.

At this particular value, the solution takes a value higher than that I am able to represent on my iMac.

```
$MaxMachineNumber
```

1.79769*10^308

So the second-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation is highly divergent.

```
ns = {5, 9, 18, 25};
Table[sol[n][x_] = 
   NDSolveValue[{y''[x] == y'[x] (Log[y[x]] + x y'[x]/y[x]), 
     y'[0] == 1, y[0] == n}, y[x], {x, 10^-15, 1.581}, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 30, WorkingPrecision -> 30], {n, ns}];
Plot[Table[If[# > 0, #, Indeterminate] &@sol[n][x], {n, ns}], {x, 0, 
  2}, PlotRange -> {0, 200}, PlotPoints -> 30, GridLines -> Automatic,
  ImageSize -> 600, AspectRatio -> 0.4, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, 
 AxesLabel -> {X, Y}]
```

[image: plot of the table of solutions]

This has two advantages:
a) no messages from NDSolve,
b) the PlotRange is still limit by y-values.

This means the domain is correctly calculated by `NDSolve` indicated by the x range of 0 to 2 despite the values are not representable in machine precision.

As indicated by Wolfram Inc in the Mathematica documentation `NDSolve` without any options set by the user is the by far most powerful setting for nonlinear second-order ordinary differential equations especially for equations under stiffness suspiciousness.

I added AccuracyGoal because both options work smoothly together. Mind, these added options usually make the stiffness if present much more difficult for the set of methods available through NDSolve. That this works properly and really fast is an indicator that the changes I did work really well.

The given problem has numerical by the change to the only positive values less problems. Compare:

```
ListLinePlot[
 Differences[
  Reap[NDSolve[{y''[x] == y'[x] (Log[y[x]] + x y'[x]/y[x]), 
      y'[0] == 1, y[0] == 25}, y, {x, 10^-15, 1.58}, 
     Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
         "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
           "MinPoints" -> 1}}}, StepMonitor :> Sow[x]]][[2, 1]]]]
```

[image: Stepwise differences plot for ns=25]

to

```
ListLinePlot[
 Differences[
  Reap[NDSolve[{y''[x] == y'[x] (Log[y[x]] + x y'[x]/y[x]), 
      y'[0] == 1, y[0] == 25}, y, {x, -0.1, 1.588}, 
     Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
         "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
           "MinPoints" -> 1}}}, StepMonitor :> Sow[x]]][[2, 1]]]]
```

[image: Stepwise differences plot for ns=25 with the interval of integration starting at x-0.1]

Wolfram Inc states to the negative values in the plot of the difference, "these steps are rejected" in the documentation of [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) section EvaluationMonitor. StepMonitor is the same as EvaluationMonitor. This stems from the section Options where the combination of AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal and WorkingPrecision is suggested too.

**Analysis of the nonlinear second-order ordinary differential equation**

This equation has a divergent homogeneous solution since it is second-order, linear functions are a solution.

Since the right-hand-side factors into the first derivative and a sum of the logarithm of the function and a quotient of the first derivative with the function times x this constant has to be used in the variation method:

y[x]=ax, y`[x]=a, y``[x]=0 for the left-hand side

makes on the right-hand side a (Log[a x]+1) and that is valid is a function
or x takes a special value x=1/(a e) for all a. a can not be a function. The right-hand side suppresses the homogeneous solution of the left-hand side.

The constant function is a solution for this equation and can be solved by the value at the point x=0 for all x. The constant function does not fit the boundary conditions at x=0 for the first derivative.

Both built-ins are acceptable for this question.

As a further illustration:

```
ListLinePlot[
 Differences[
  Reap[NDSolveValue[{y''[x] == y'[x] (Log[y[x]] + x y'[x]/y[x]), 
      y'[0] == 1, y[0] == 25}, y, {x, -1.588, 0}, 
     Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
         "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
           "MinPoints" -> 1}}}, StepMonitor :> Sow[x]]][[2, 1]]]]
```

[image: plot of fail for negative values]

It seems to me that NDSolveValue might be too an response to multivalueness but it is just more a pointwise solution than a complete different set of methods to NDSolve. In the section Possible Issues Multiple Solutions is named by Wolfram Inc.. This does not appear for NDSolve.